SQL using ROWS BETWEEN to aggregate 12 months, nulls included?
I'm currently working with a table with the following columns:

Supplier
itemnumber
invoice_year_numerical
invoice_month_numerical
invoice date
invoice amount
invoice qty

I'm using SUM(invoice amount) to get X.TotalInvoiceSpend for the current month, this needs to be compared with Total Invoice amount from the last 12 months.
I am using ROWS BETWEEN to aggregate last 12 month but if there is no invoice for a month, the query skips it and moves to past years.
Any suggestion idea on how to handle this scenario so that it only  until 12 months include NULL values? Example: for February 2024, baseline should come from February 2023 to January 2024, but if no invoice exist for February 2023, the query should not move to next value.
HELP?
I tried this
SELECT
    x.normalized_supplier_name_inv,
    x.item_number, 
    x.item_description,
    x.SiteID, x.country_po,
    x.country_inv,
    x.Year_Number, x.Month_Number,
    SUM(x.TotalInvoiceSpend) OVER(PARTITION BY X.normalized_supplier_name_inv, X.item_number,X.SiteID     
                                  ORDER BY x.normalized_supplier_name_inv, x.item_number, x.SiteID, x.Year_Number, x.Month_Number 
                                  ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS BaselineSpend,
    X.TotalInvoiceSpend
FROM 
    (SELECT
         cp.normalized_supplier_name_inv,
         cp.item_number,
         cp.item_description,
         cp.location_inv as SiteID,
         CAST(cp.inv_date_year_numerical AS INTEGER) AS Year_Number,
         CAST(cp.inv_date_month_numerical AS INTEGER) AS Month_Number,
         SUM(cp.invoice_spend_usd) AS TotalInvoiceSpend,
         SUM(cp.invoice_quantity) AS TotalInvcdQty
     FROM
         invoice_flat AS cp) X


Please update your question to supply sample data, desired results, and a [mre].

The query shown is invalid. Two immediately obvious issues are that subquery x include SUM without GROUP BY or window expressions, and it doesn't return columns country_po or country_inv used in the outer query.
